# (rdlc) HOW to extract/display values of an array parameter

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, parameters, rdlc

Calling all RDLC expert out there.

When displaying the values of the parameter(which the values is in array) to a tablix or table, it only displays the first value data of the array.

Which looks like this.
[image]

I want to display the 626 datas of the array to be displayed individually in rows.

There are about 626 datas inside the array named `Testparameter`, but it seems to that it only displays the first value of the array.

Maybe I must be missing something in the expression in reproducing the values.

This is the expression that I am using

```
=Parameters!Testparameter.Value
```

I have also tried `JOIN` expression but it displays all the 626 datas inside the column.

```
=Join(Parameters!Testparameter.Value,", ")
```

Whic resulted to this.
[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? or is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the dates returned from the parameter have an enter (\n) or some spaces, what you can try is to replace all the string \n or spaces to empty string and check.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by enter or spaces. But for your information those spaces is from the database. so even if it has spaces in it, it wont be a problem. 

I think your suggestion would not display the values individually on each rows.